# GETTING CURRENT DATE then will output 2 cutoff per month

Tags: sql-server

I want to get the current date in SQL then it will automatically output cutoff for this date.

```
select cast(getdate() AS DATE)
```

Example: date today is 6/13/2019 then it should output a 2nd cut off for this month

```
6/11/2019 - 6/25/2019
```

If I select 6/10/2019 then the output should be

```
5/26/2019 - 6/10/2019
```

Comment: Would you mind telling us what is the logic to get the 2 dates ?

Comment: the 1st cut off will be 11 - 25 of the month then 2nd cutoff will be 26 to 10 of the next month so basically it should have 2 cut off per month and if i get the current date it should output the cutoff date

Comment: Hi sir its fixed

Comment: Look up `DATEFROMPARTS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
 Declare @Get_Date date=getdate()

Select iif
        (
            Datepart(day,@Get_Date)<11 or Datepart(day,@Get_Date) between 26 and 31
            ,Format(Dateadd(day,-5,EOMONTH(@Get_Date,iif(Datepart(day,@Get_Date) between 26 and 31,0,-1))),'dd/MM/yyyy')
            ,Format(Dateadd(day,11,EOMONTH(@Get_Date,-1)),'dd/MM/yyyy')
        ) as Cutoff_Start_Date,
        iif
        (
            Datepart(day,@Get_Date)<11 or Datepart(day,@Get_Date) between 26 and 31
            ,Format(Dateadd(day,10,EOMONTH(@Get_Date,iif(Datepart(day,@Get_Date) between 26 and 31,0,-1))),'dd/MM/yyyy')
            ,Format(Dateadd(day,25,EOMONTH(@Get_Date,-1)),'dd/MM/yyyy')
        ) as Cutoff_End_Date
```

Comment: this is exactly what i need thank you very much sir

Comment: by the way sir how should i make it on a different column?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use something like

```
Declare datetime @CurrentDate = GetDate(); -- 13Jun19 04:13:23
Declare datetime @D25OfMonth = GetDate() - DatePart(day, GetDate()) + 25; --25Jun19 04:13:23
Declare datetime @D10OfMonth = GetDate() - DatePart(day, GetDate()) + 11; --11Jun19 04:13:23
```

but there's a catch here. where in the day do you want the cuttoff to be (midnight, current hour, noon)? You're basically manipulating the datetime by adding an integer, thus moving one day forward (+) or backwards (-).